# A gametree with variable choices

Tags: tikz-trees

Hello everybody i am making a simple game tree using tikz, i am almost done but i need som finishing tuches to make it just right. This is the code so far

```
\hspace{.1in}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(0){Firm 1}
child{node(11){\( E_2 \)}
child{node{\( 0 \)}}
child{node(21){\( q_1 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node{\( q_2 \)}
        child{node{\( \begin{pmatrix}
                \Pi^{c_{2}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{c}_{2}\\ \Pi^{m}_{3}
                \end{pmatrix} \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node(12){\( E_3 \)}
child{node{\( 0 \)}}
child{node(22){\( q_1 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node{\( q_3 \)}
        child{node{\( \begin{pmatrix}
                \Pi^{c_{3}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{m}_{2}\\ \Pi^{c}_{3}
                \end{pmatrix} \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node{\( \infty \)}} 
};
\draw[dashed](11-1)to(11-3);
\draw[dashed](12-1)to(12-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What i would like to do is to move the q_1 nodes so that there are not on the dashed line. Also i would like a downward arch between 0 and infinity going from the middle of the brach. (So not from the nodes but halfway between them) It is to symbolize that the q values can be anything between 0 and infinity. I hope my question makes sence, else feel free to ask :-)

Looking forward to your answers

Cheers
Steffen

Comment: Hi, please make you code compilable and as small as possible. If you want to learn how to do that, one q_1 node should be enough here. Just giving an example on how to reduce. Thank you.

Comment: Is `\raisebox{15pt}{$q_1$}` what you want?

Comment: Hi i do not know how to make it compilable? can you show me how? And raisebox works grat

Comment: Just look on the answers. These are compilable examples. You can just copy them and press on your build button and you are done. We do not know, which packages you need for your drawing or in which documentclass you are working. So this would be important information when asking something.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be one of your possible solution where, instead, the solution moves the dashed line above a little so that q_1 is not on the dashed line, which shows what you want.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\hspace{.1in}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(0){Firm 1}
child{node[](11){\( E_2 \)}
child{node{\( 0 \)}}
child{node(21){\( q_1 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node{\( q_2 \)}
        child{node{\(\begin{pmatrix}
                \Pi^{c_{2}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{c}_{2}\\ \Pi^{m}_{3}
                \end{pmatrix} \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node(12){\( E_3 \)}
child{node{\( 0 \)}}
child{node(22){\( q_1 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node{\( q_3 \)}
        child{node{\( \begin{pmatrix}
                \Pi^{c_{3}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{m}_{2}\\ \Pi^{c}_{3}
                \end{pmatrix} \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node{\( \infty \)}} 
};
\draw[dashed]([yshift=4ex]$(11-1)!0.55!(21)$) to[bend right] ([yshift=4ex]$(21)!0.5!(11-3)$);
\draw[dashed]([yshift=4ex]$(12-1)!0.55!(22)$) to[bend right]([yshift=4ex]$(22)!0.5!(12-3)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another example of using the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package (version 2.0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[semithick]
\tikzset{oval node/.style={box node,draw=none,minimum size=5mm}}
\cntmdistance*{20mm}{25mm}
\istrooto(0)[plain node]{Firm 1}+15mm..50mm+
  \istb \istb \endist
\setistmathTF111
\cntmApreset[dashed,thick]{.6}
\istrootocntmA(E2)(0-1){E_2}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(cntm-1){0}    \xtNode*(cntm-2){\infty}
\istrootocntmA(E3)(0-2){E_3}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(cntm-1){0}    \xtNode*(cntm-2){\infty}
\istrootocntmA(11)(E2-1){q_1}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(cntm-1){0}    \xtNode*(cntm-2){\infty}
\istrootocntmA(21)(E3-1){q_1}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(cntm-1){0}    \xtNode*(cntm-2){\infty}
\istrooto(3a)(11-1){q_2}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(3a-1){\big(\prod\big)_1^{c_2}\prod_2^c\prod_3^m}
\istrooto(3b)(21-1){q_3}  \istb[thin]  \endist
\xtNode*(3b-1){\big(\prod\big)_1^{c_3}\prod_2^m\prod_3^c}
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My sincere compliments for your answer and for the knowledge of another package.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not very beautiful (you should use Jesse's instead), as it increases the space below the dashed line, but it is very easy to do.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(0){Firm 1}
child{node(11){\( E_2 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node(21){\raisebox{15pt}{$q_1$}}
        child{node{\( 0 \)}}
        child{node{\( q_2 \)}
            child{node{\(\begin{pmatrix}\Pi^{c_{2}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{c}_{2}\\ \Pi^{m}_{3}\end{pmatrix}\)}}}
        child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
child{node(12){\( E_3 \)}
    child{node{\( 0 \)}}
    child{node(22){\raisebox{15pt}{$q_1$}}
        child{node{\( 0 \)}}
        child{node{\( q_3 \)}
            child{node{\(\begin{pmatrix}\Pi^{c_{3}}_{1} \\ \Pi^{m}_{2}\\ \Pi^{c}_{3}\end{pmatrix}\)}}}
        child{node{\( \infty \)}}}
    child{node{\( \infty \)}} 
};
\draw[dashed](11-1)to(11-3);
\draw[dashed](12-1)to(12-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]